# Is there a way to change the current mail view to another folder Outlook for Mac with keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: macos, microsoft-outlook, keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-outlook-2010

I use a lot of folders in Outlook/Exchange and rules for automatically sorting incoming mail. I know that there are shortcuts like:

- <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>1</kbd> = Mail
- <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>2</kbd> = Calendar
- <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>3</kbd> = Contacts

... and so on. I've also found that <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> (Move message) is useful for manually sorting mail.

Are there any shortcuts that will allow me to change the current mail view to another folder. Something like <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>M</kbd>, but instead of moving the current message it would change my view to that folder, would be perfect.

I also did a quick look into the custom keyboard shortcuts functionality in OSX System Preferences, but you can only use that to call an existing menu item with no shortcut defined and I can't find what I want to do on a menu, so that doesn't appear to be of any help either.

If it makes a difference, I'm using Outlook 2010.